# CoreData Object typing won't work

Tags: iphone, core-data, properties, nsmanagedobject

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work:

```
CoreDataClass *classObject = (CoreDataClass *)[some method that returns a dictionary with exact KVC pairs that match CoreDataClass];

NSString *myString = classObject.stringProperty;
```

But this does:

```
CoreDataClass *classObject = (CoreDataClass *)[some method that returns a dictionary with exact KVC pairs that match CoreDataClass];
NSString *myString = [classObject valueForKey:@"stringProperty"];
```

EDIT:
What's the easiest way to cast the dictionary as my NSManagedObjectClass CoreDataClass so I can access properties directly?

Comment: You cast a dictionary to some very different class and expect it to work? Good luck!

Comment: they aren't different, the class has the same KVC pairs. What's the fastest wait to turn a KVC compliant dictionary to a matching NSManagedObject Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting objects only *appears to work* (in the sense that you won't get type-checking errors) because it's a hint to the compiler, but it doesn't actually change anything about what the pointer points to, so you are still pointing to an NSDictionary. This is because, at the end of the day, you are essentially casting a pointer to a pointer, but telling Xcode that you are allowed to send a different set of selectors to it.

For NSManagedObjects, creation from a dictionary depends on a few things, but the recommended way is to make a class method on your custom class which will use NSEntityDescription and you NSManagedObjectContext, and sets the properties from the dictionary to the object:

```
+(CoreDataClass *) coreDataObjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *) spec {
  CoreDataClass *myInstance = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"CoreDataClass" inManagedObjectContext: [myMOCProvider sharedMOC];
  myInstance.someProp = [spec valueForKey:@"someProp"];
}
```

Comment: So the method above makes me insert a record into the MOClass so I can access it directly as the class?

Comment: It uses the managed object context to manage the new object's relationship to the store, and it uses the MOC's configured *model* and *persistent store* to know what to build and how to insert it into your database. So the net result (if you are using SQLite, for instance) is that a new object is created of your configured class for that entity, and when you save the MOC, a row will be inserted in your SQL store. In the future, you can/should load that object with an NSFetchRequest instead of this method, which would duplicate it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work since KVC compliance is not at all what defines classes or makes them castable - the class hierarchy exists for a reason, and just ensuring adherence to certain methods doesn't magically make something an instance of a completely different class. Keep in mind that the dot-accessor syntax is just sugar for a method send, so these two are equivalent:

- `classObject.stringProperty`
- `[classObject stringProperty]`

...and the latter obviously isn't valid for instances of NSDictionary (i.e. `[[NSDictionary class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(stringProperty)]` is `NO`).

Your latter example works because of the very premise of your question: if something is KVC-compliant for the key `stringProperty`, and you ask it for a value for that key, then obviously you get something back. Furthermore, both NSDictionary and CoreDataClass respond to the selector `-valueForKey:`, so the message send actually works at runtime.

The best way to get the two across isn't a "cast" at all - it's a complete conversion, at the property level, of the data involved. You might consider creating a custom `-initWith...` method on CoreDataClass that lets you instantiate its properties from a dictionary, or finding a way to get your method to return an actual instance of CoreDataClass instead of an NSDictionary.

Note that this solution may differ from the "easiest" way to get the data across, which is effectively to keep doing what you're doing and use `-valueForKey:` (though preferably without the cast, which is misleading).